# Editing a question that is "on-hold"

Tags: support, bug

TL;DR: Is my inability to edit my on-hold question a bug (perhaps related to the fact that I am a new user following migration of the question)?

My [on-hold question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24298/why-is-interest-in-the-fields-of-ontology-and-semantics-declining) has a note at the bottom that says

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question or leave a comment.

Similarly, the [help page for closed questions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) states:

> Questions are marked [on hold] for the first five days after closure to encourage edits and improvements to the question.

However, I can not click the edit button,

[image]

nor can I comment

[image]

Is this a feature? Or a bug?

Answer (score 2):

When migrated questions are closed, they enter a special state. The basic assumption is "the question is crap" so there would be no need to edit. Clearly, this assumptions flawed; see also [this meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218412/migrations-should-not-be-rejected-while-question-is-on-hold).

The fact is that such questions get locked against edits. Moderators can clear this; I'll be doing this for your question now.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the text at the bottom, I see:

> **migration rejected** from [cstheory.stackexchange.com](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/posts/22374/revisions)
>   15 hours ago
>
> This question came from our site for theoretical computer scientists
>   and researchers in related fields. Votes, comments, and answers are
>   locked due to the question being closed here, but it may be eligible
>   for editing and reopening on the site where it originated.

so it sounds like you should be editing the version that you posted originally on cstheory: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22374/why-is-interest-in-the-fields-of-ontology-and-semantics-declining

The text definitely indicates that it's a feature (though as people have pointed out, that leaves something to be desired for your cs.stackexchange post)

---

(Added after comments)

As people have pointed out, a moderator can unlock the post so that you can edit once more. Given that the lock appears to be automatic, it looks like the standard procedure would be to flag for moderator attention and ask that it be unlocked (though in this case, Raphael already took care of it).

Comment: Ok. I didn't realize it got sent back. I am beginning to suspect that there is an conspiracy of Ontologists

Comment: Editing the question on [cstheory.SE] won't change the post here.

Comment: Let me emphasis "_may be_" in that statement.